# When is it ok to assert for a pointer being non-null?

Tags: c++, pointers, assertions

This came up as part of a code review for a code segment which resembled this:

```
auto somePikachu = GetMeAPikachu();
NT_ASSERT(somePikachu != nullptr); // this only fires on debug build
somePikachu->ThunderBolt();
```

In my opinion that assert is redundant since if `somePikachu` is `null` it will crash anyway in the next line when it tries to call `Thunderbolt`. (Of course if  `ThunderBolt` doesn't require dereferencing this pointer nothing will happen on release build). So the assert is not buying anything IMHO. 
There is another school of thought that was of the opinion that the assert adds value to readability and makes the intent of the design clear. 
I would like to get the opinion of the community on the correct pattern of asserting the design for validity of pointers. 
Please feel free to include other possible scenarios that match the problem statement.

Comment: The assert changes the semantics of the code from "in situation X undefined behaviour occurs" to "In situation X an assertion is raised". I'm pretty firmly convinced that that's a big improvement.

Comment: You should also be asking yourself what conditions would cause `GetMeAPikachu()` to return a `nullptr` and what you should do in those cases if crashing in production isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: The assertion is not redundant because under certain situations, calling a function on a null pointer won't crash.

Comment: Do you have a test case where GetMeAPikachu returns nullptr?

Comment: @17of26:  In C++, dereferencing the pointer is not one of those situations.

Comment: @Blrfl:  Not true.  Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.  I have personally debugged scenarios where functions were called on a null pointer did not crash as long as they didn't access member data.

Comment: @17of26:  I stand corrected.  What kind of unit tests would you recommend for undefined behavior?

Comment: The problem with undefined behavior is that it's undefined :).  This makes it impossible to create a test for it.

Comment: John Lakos' presentation _Defensive programming done right_ talks about this in great detail. [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QhtXRMp3Hg) [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz2khnjnUx8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of the assertion is:

- It explicitly documents the assumption of the programmer that `GetMeAPikachu` returns non-null. This is especially valuable if the function at some point in history changed behavior, or if there are specific circumstances in which the function can return null, but the programmer is asserting that these circumstances don't apply here.
- It turns the error situation from "there was a crash, now go and find the reason" into "this pointer was null".
- It is independent of the implementation details of `ThunderBolt`. If that function isn't virtual and doesn't access member variables itself, the crash could simply not happen at all, or be deep within the call tree, and it might be not an access violation, but possibly an illegal instruction because you eventually managed to jump through an invalid function pointer/vtable.

Answer (score -5):

> When is it ok to assert for a pointer being non-null?

I would tell you that it is never ok to use assert.

If the condition fails, then the program terminates. It gives you some debug information, but the effect is the same - not something you want the users of your application to see.

If you define NDEBUG, then the check goes away. But in a case when somehow that condition is met, then your application will most likely end with some kind of undefined behaviour.

So, what to do if the condition is not met? Throw an exception.

And in the exception handler, you can try to fix the problem. If it is not possible, then ask for user's assistance.

Comment: I have seen, used and found asserts to be quite useful specially during development phase. They help in catching errors early. What is shipped to the users is usually the release build where these statements are no-op.

Comment: I disagree with you that it's never ok to assert. I would much rather assert and have a clear error as soon as possible, than "hide" the root cause of the issue. Failing fast is IMHO a completely valid way of avoiding the user seeing the errors, as they will be really prominent during development.

Comment: Is `ASSERT` not dependent on the `DEBUG` define, and therefore will never be visible to the end-user?

Comment: @kat0r It is, but if the assert fails, then you are may end in the UB land. In the above example, the pointer's value is nullptr. You should be happy when it crashes, cause of that.

Comment: @martiert Throwing an exception is certainly not hiding the error, since you have to handle it somewhere.

Comment: though I tend to agree with this answer, "never" is a bit strong, there are cases where you cannot use Exceptions in C++ so assert is pretty much it.

Comment: asserts are ok to throw for preconditions and postconditions. Preconditions and postconditions are conditions that you assume/trust to be satisfied, without checking explicitly in the code (for example, I would appreciate having an assert for null pointer in std::strlen: calling it is only defined behavior on a non-null pointer, and the function doesn't check/handle the null case). I would appreciate more an assert failure on null, than a core dump in this case.

Comment: @BЈовић If it hides errors or not really depends on how you catch the exception. In my opinion a catch_all exception is way to common (I actually have a running argument with a colleague about it now). So for exceptions you assume the user can recover from, throw an exception and let someone try to recover. For other errors the best thing to do (IMHO) is just to die and flag to the developer that it went wrong. Dying at a customer location is of course bad, but the danger of hiding errors is in my opinion far too real.

Comment: @utnapistim I see no difference in failing the assert or getting a code dump, except in the later case - you get the backtrace. It is better to throw an exception if the preconditions and postconditions are not met. At least you get the same binary, regardless if some macro is defined (assert is removed when NDEBUG is defined). And that is important when debugging very hard to find bugs, which happen once in a blue moon.

Comment: @martiert The exceptions handler can try to recover, or ask the user to fix the problem (wrong argument, missing device, etc). From assert, it is not possible to recover. You can restart the program, but guess how many people love doing it. Once you lose whole hour of work, you'll figure out the answer.

Comment: @BЈовић If the exception is thrown due to a programming error I would still much rather have it fail during development. If I write an internal only library which have hard requirements on inputs, I would not hesitate to have it assert on that. The user will then get a proper error thrown in his face that he have to fix before going into production. Crashing programs are annoying, but programs that suddenly gets weird behaviour because they are trying to conceal bugs are IMHO even worse.

Comment: @martiert That is not a proper error, since the user may not see it. How many people actually starts anything from console? Much better is to actually ask the user to assistance. Looks like you do not understand the exceptions, since you write such comments.

Comment: @BЈовић, you seem to consider asserts to be an error handling mechanism (they are not);  You also seem to consider preconditions as conditions that an API must check upon entrance - that is, it seems you confuse preconditions with error conditions (they are not; they are instead conditions assumed to be true in all cases - that is, without checing). If preconditions are not respected, your application should not be able to run at all (not exit with an error message - that would be an error condition, not a precondition).

Comment: @BЈовић I'm not saying exceptions are wrong to use, I'm just saying they are not a big shiny hammer that should be used for everything. IMO exceptions should not be used to hide programming errors. Programming errors should be visible as soon as possible, ideally at compile time, or in a test. Someone putting illegal arguments into a library is IMO a programming error. And no one was talking about console either, even though a lot of what we write don't directly have a UI (embedded), so it's not that uncommon.